# select count(*) multiple rows and display result

Tags: mysql, select, count, rows

I have to do an UPDATE table that includes a SELECT COUNT but that takes way too long. 
That was my original query

```
 UPDATE list SET count = 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_1 WHERE set_1.start BETWEEN list.start AND list.end);
```

I just have 100 rows to update so I was thinking of just do a select count and display it on screen. And then I'll copy/paste the result on my excel spreadsheet.

I was intended to do this, but it returns only one number (and not 100 rows of number)

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_1,list WHERE set_1.start BETWEEN list.start AND list.end;
```

But that doesn't work it returns one big number of all the SELECT COUNT together ..

Anyone can help me out with this ?

Comment: do you mean you want to edit only 100 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a cartesian product between set1 and list

```
select        
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_1 
         WHERE set_1.start BETWEEN list.start AND list.end) as [count]
from list
```

Comment: true .. I just tried but I thought that would be faster. If I do just one select count(*) on one row it takes 0.02sec. If I query on 10 rows it takes 1 min 6.07 sec. so 100 rows it goes exponentially. I don't understand why does the time increase exponentially ..

Comment: add an index on set_1 table for set_1.start column, see what happens

Comment: probably select count(1) will be faster, I'm not familiar with mysql

Comment: @ Adrian Iftode : I haven't tried the select count(1) will try now ~~ Thanks

Comment: @ Adrian Iftode : select count(1) is actually a bit slower (tested on 10 rows)